# Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train a Neural Network model using Keras and need help with this error, which occurs when I try to run my train model:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 19990 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
```

The code can be found here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hgQoo7Oz6UPIzQQ4ELwRUuPPNxaOAqeh?usp=sharing

Comment: without your code can't tell what is happening

Comment: Is the error happening during training or final evaluation? Which is the block of code in the Colab file where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `fit()` instead of `fit_generator()` method as TensorFlow already suggesting you.

However, coming back to your issue, what's causing the problem actually is, when using generators you should let the model figure out how many steps are needed for an epoch to complete. **If you manually set** `steps_per_epoch` then **you need to compute it correctly** by yourself (`steps_per_epoch=(data_samples/batch_size)`), and with wrong calculation, this error occurs (that's what happened in your case). So **to prevent this issue** you should **simply remove the `step_per_epoch`** parameter when calling the `fit_generator()` method and let the model handle `step_per_epoch` value by itself, the code should work fine then.